# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to Display Only the Mandates of the Logged In User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API. I have these models:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }
}

public class Merchant : EntityBase
{
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mandate> Mandates { get; set; }
}

public class Mandate : EntityBase
{
    public int? MerchantId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MerchantId")]
    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
}
```

**Models: User, Mandate and Merchant**

***User details are in Merchant Table. A Merchant can have many mandates.***

ViewModel (Dto):

```
public class MandateGetDto
{
    public int? MerchantId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

EntityMapper:

```
    public MandateGetDto FromMandateToMandateGetDto(Mandate mandate)
    {
        MandateGetDto mandateDto = new MandateGetDto();
        mandateDto.MerchantId = mandate.MerchantId;
        mandateDto.DueDate = mandate.DueDate;
        mandateDto.StartDate = mandate.StartDate;
        mandateDto.EndDate = mandate.EndDate;

        return mandateDto;
    }
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    #region Mandate
    private readonly IBaseRepository<Mandate> _mandateRepository;

    public IBaseRepository<Mandate> MandateRepository => _mandateRepository ?? new BaseRepository<Mandate>(_context);
    # endregion

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

MandateService:

```
    public async Task<ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>>> GetAll(int page, int sizeByPage)
    {
        string nextRoute = null, previousRoute = null;
        IEnumerable<Mandate> data = await _unitOfWork.MandateRepository.GetAll();

        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var mandatesDto = data.Select(m => mapper.FromMandateToMandateGetDto(m)).ToList();

        GenericPagination<MandateGetDto> objGenericPagination = GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>.Create(mandatesDto, page, sizeByPage);
        ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>> response = new ResponsePagination<GenericPagination<MandateGetDto>>(objGenericPagination);
        response.CurrentPage = objGenericPagination.CurrentPage;
        response.HasNextPage = objGenericPagination.HasNextPage;
        response.HasPreviousPage = objGenericPagination.HasPreviousPage;
        response.PageSize = objGenericPagination.PageSize;
        response.TotalPages = objGenericPagination.TotalPages;
        response.TotalRecords = objGenericPagination.TotalRecords;
        response.Data = objGenericPagination;

        if (response.HasNextPage)
        {
            nextRoute = $"/mandates?page={(page + 1)}";
            response.NextPageUrl = _uriPaginationService.GetPaginationUri(page, nextRoute).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            response.NextPageUrl = null;
        }

        if (response.HasPreviousPage)
        {
            previousRoute = $"/mandates?page={(page - 1)}";
            response.PreviousPageUrl = _uriPaginationService.GetPaginationUri(page, previousRoute).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            response.PreviousPageUrl = null;
        }
        return response;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Mandate>> GetMandates()
    {
        return await _unitOfWork.MandateRepository.GetAll();
    }
```

What I have currently is displaying all the Mandates.
How do I Make the Logged In user to get only His Mandates?

Thanks

Comment: You're storing passwords in plain text. Don't do that! [Secure Password Authentication Explained Simply](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54164/Secure-Password-Authentication-Explained-Simply)

Comment: @RichardDeeming - I will do that. But it's not the main issue. Kindly assist with the main Issue. Thanks

Comment: You need to filter the data returned from your repository. Depending on your setup, perhaps a [global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) might work?

Comment: @RichardDeeming - Is it possible to give a sample from my code? Thanks

Comment: [Filter user records using Global Query Filters](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/filter-user-records-using-global-query-filter/)